# Negative binomial regression in R using brm causing error when using multiple cores

Tags: r, sockets, parallel-processing, non-linear-regression, r-4.0.0

I am calculating a negative binomial regression using the `brm` function from the `brms` package. As this takes quite some time, I would like to use multiple cores as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/brms/versions/2.12.0/topics/brm).

```
bfit_s <- brm(
  dep_var ~ ind_var +
    var1 +
    var2 +
    (1 | some_level1) + (1 | some_level2),
  data = my_df,
  family = negbinomial(link = "log", link_shape = "log"),
  cores = 4,
  control = list(adapt_delta = 0.999)
)
```

However, I am running into an error saying that the connection of all four workers failed:

```
Compiling the C++ model

Start sampling
starting worker pid=11603 on localhost:11447 at 14:13:56.193
starting worker pid=11601 on localhost:11447 at 14:13:56.193
starting worker pid=11602 on localhost:11447 at 14:13:56.198
starting worker pid=11604 on localhost:11447 at 14:13:56.201
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: <Anonymous> -> slaveLoop -> makeSOCKmaster
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: <Anonymous> -> slaveLoop -> makeSOCKmaster
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: <Anonymous> -> slaveLoop -> makeSOCKmaster
Execution halted
Execution halted
Execution halted
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
Calls: <Anonymous> -> slaveLoop -> makeSOCKmaster
Execution halted
```

The traceback says `Error in makePSOCKcluster(names = spec, ...) : Cluster setup failed. 4 of 4 workers failed to connect.`

I tried to understand the problem, read some questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248598/cant-open-sockets-for-parallel-cluster), but couldn't figure out why I can't connect. I'm using macOS Mojave and the problem is not that I try to use more cores than possible. Any suggestions on how I could get this to run on multiple cores?

---

Edit:
As sjp pointed out in his answer, there is an issue with RStudio. I thought I share the code to solve the problem right here in my question, so everyone stumbling across can solve this without clicking (and reading) any further.

The problem is the `parallel` package from R-4.0.0. - but a workaround is provided by a user from [this](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/r-4-0-0-and-cran-macos-binaries/13989/19) stan forum. If you can initialize clusters with  `setup_strategy="sequential"` like this:

```
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, setup_strategy = "sequential")
```

You can add a short snippet to your `~/.Rprofile` to make this kind of a default setting:

```
## WORKAROUND: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692
## Revert to 'sequential' setup of PSOCK cluster in RStudio Console on macOS and R 4.0.0
if (Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO") == "1" && !nzchar(Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_TERM")) && 
    Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Darwin" && getRversion() == "4.0.0") {
  parallel:::setDefaultClusterOptions(setup_strategy = "sequential")
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57561005/8245406) can be of help. Also, try writing a script and run it from the command line with `Rscript script_name.R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that has to do with RStudio. Check out these related posts on the Stan forums and Github.

Github: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6692

Stan forums: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/r-4-0-0-and-cran-macos-binaries/13989/13

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!